# Page not found error when adding Facebook authentication

Tags: django, facebook-login, python-social-auth

I'm following Django-3-by-Example. I followed all instructions but reached a dead spot with a page not found error. I checked FB dev

[Error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liIOQ.png)

**settings.py**

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'XXXXXXXXX'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['mysite.com', 'localhost', '127.0.0.1']


# Application definition


INSTALLED_APPS = [
#my apps
    'account.apps.AccountConfig',
    'social_django',
    'django_extensions',
#pre intalled apps
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'bookmarks.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'bookmarks.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'dashboard'
LOGIN_URL = 'login'
LOGOUT_URL = 'logout'
#LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'login'


EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'account.authentication.EmailAuthBackend',
    'social_core.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',
    # 'social_core.backends.twitter.TwitterOAuth',
    # 'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',
]

# social auth settings
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY = 'XXXXXXX' # Facebook App ID
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SECRET = 'XXXXX' # Facebook App Secret
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE = ['email']
```

**Main urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('account/', include('account.urls')),
    path('social-auth/', include('social_django.urls', namespace='social')),
]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**FB Settings**
I checked the Redirect URI Validator it returns the link is valid
The Facebook login settings. May be I'm missing something or need to add some configuration. Appreciate guidance.

[Facebook settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEmSz.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. I changed the url path as below:

path('account/login/social-auth/', include('social_django.urls', namespace='social') and now everything works